# simple forEach returning undefined, I move a console.log and it works - why?

Tags: javascript

Thank you - I am not sure why this returns undefined.

```
function whatever() {
    return arr.forEach(function(x) {
        return x;
    })
};
console.log(whatever());
```

But this works?

```
function whatever() {
    return arr.forEach(function(x) {
        return console.log(x);
    })
};
whatever();
```

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

How would I separate the console.log from the logic?

Comment: `forEach` is a function, and as any function, it has a return value. In its particular case, is `undefined` (no matter what its parameter - a callback - returns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zimri-leijen has mentioned forEach is a simple iterator which does not return anything.

But you can use `.map` property if you want to perform operation on elements and return something on indexes.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
function withForeach() {
    return arr.forEach(function(x) {
        return x; // nothing is returned
    })
};

function withMap() {
    return arr.map(function(x) {
        return x+5; // value is returned
    })
};
console.log('foreach : ', withForeach());
console.log('map: ', withMap());
```

Comment: @anees Ijaz thank you for your detailed response - it is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

because [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value) doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` in `javascript` is like a simple for Loop. it just iterate over the array and perform the action on each element but return nothing. That is why in second case, it calls the console.log on each item which just prints it. Even if you don't return console.log, it will still behave the same.

So if you want the iterator to return the element after each iteration, better to use `map`. The best thing about `map` is that it always returns a new array after performing action on each element. So total immutability.

The above function using `map` can be written as:

```
function whatever() {
  return arr.map(function(x) {
    return x;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> Return value:`undefined`

We can expand the first block of code to get equivalent code like this:

```js
function whatever() {
    const result =  arr.forEach(function(x) {
        return x;
    })
    return result // undefined
};
console.log(whatever()); // undefined
```

Comment: That's exactly the same thing. You're still effectively returning undefined.

If you want to return something, like Anees said, you should use map instead.

Comment: @ZimriLeijen yes, I updated my comment, the point is showing him why the code got undefined step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Consider only your first function. When you call it `whatever()` you also get output `undefined`, but you don't display it in console.

```
function whatever() {
    return [].forEach(function(x) {
        return x;
    })
};

console.log(whatever()) //output "undefined"
whatever() // nothing happens
```

Answer (score 0):

forEach() method is giving elements in an array one by one....
If you try to returm something in a forEach() method, it returns undefined..

If you tell me what exactly you waht to do, then i can help you....